# youtube-dl - do not download subtitles for audio-only

Tags: youtube-dl

I have these options in my youtube-dl.conf:

```
--write-sub
--write-auto-sub
--sub-lang en,fr
--embed-subs
```

Now youtube-dl saves downloaded subs in a container, so that I don't have separate subtitle files.

But when I download only audio, I still get subtitles and they go as separate files since they can't be merged into an mp3. I pass these options to command line:

```
--extract-audio --audio-format mp3
```

How can I disable subtitle download for audio-only files?

One idea that comes to mind is to create a separate config file for audio downloads. I have these aliases in my .bashrc:

```
alias ytdl='youtube-dl'
alias ytdlmp3='youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3'
```

Are there options to ignore subs for audio-only? If no, what is the option to set a custom config file?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with a separate config file that doesn't include subtitle options. The option for a custom config path is `--config-location PATH`.
Also, I moved the options `--extract-audio --audio-format mp3` from .bashrc to the new config.